# Local Area Unemployment - Month-County level since 2007

Tags: data-request

I am trying to download month-county level unemployment data from the bls's LAU, but I can't find data extending earlier than the "latest 14 months." [This](http://www.bls.gov/lau/laucntycur14.txt) data set is exactly what I want EXCEPT that it does not extend far enough into the past. If that data extended to at least 2007, I would be done. I know the data is available, because I can download it county by county from the BLS multi-screen-data-search tool.

Where can I download the archives of monthly-county level LAU data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are hoping to use not seasonally adjusted monthly predictions of estimated county unemployment rates, I would suggest keeping in mind some of the changes to county borders that have taken place since 2007. For instance, there has been A LOT of changes to "county" borders in Alaska since 2007; Colorado, has had a major county border change; and Virginia has had one county wholly incorporate another county.

That being said, this [directory](http://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/la/) has what you are looking for. Be sure to read all of the smaller sized files that fully explain the meaning of the data.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - I didn't realize the borders have changed so much. I looked at that directory previously, but, in my haste, I missed that I needed to combine two of the data sets to get the county name and the data for each period. For future reference, the actual values for each county-month are in http://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/la/la.data.64.County  and the cross walk to get the county names are in  http://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/la/la.series .Thanks again!